# segmentation fault while implementing the binary tree in C

Tags: c

I got a segmentation fault in the code when I am implementing the binary tree and couldn't figure out why.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    struct tree{
        int info;
        struct tree *lptr,*rptr;
    };
    typedef struct tree node;

    node *create(int, node *);
    node *insert(node *);
    void preorder(node *);
    void inorder(node *);
    void postorder(node *);

    int main(){
        node *root=NULL;
        int n,choice=0;
        while(choice!=6){
        printf("\n\n\t\tMENU");
        printf("\n\t1:CREATE\n\t2:INSERTION\n\t3:POSTORDER");
        printf("\n\t4:INORDER\n\t5:PREORDER\n\t6:EXIT");
        printf("\n\n\tEnter your choice:\t");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice){
        case 1:
            printf("\n\tHow many elements to enter\t");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            root=NULL;
            root=create(n,root); 
        return 0;
    }

    node *create(int n, node *root){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            insert(root);
        return root;
    }           

    node *insert(node *root){
        int val;
        node *temp, *p, *parent;
        p=malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("\nEnter data for the node: ");
        scanf("%d",&val);
        p->info=val;
        p->lptr=NULL;
        p->rptr=NULL;
        if(root=NULL)
            root=p;
        else{
            temp=root;
            while(temp){
                parent=temp;
                if(val<temp->info)
                    temp=temp->lptr;
                if(val>temp->info)
                    temp=temp->rptr;    
                if(val==temp->info){
                    printf("Duplicate data!\n");
                    free(p);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!temp&&p){
                if(val<parent->info)      //SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE!!!
                     parent->lptr=p;
                if(val>parent->info)
                     parent->rptr=p;
            }           
         }
        return root;
    }

    void preorder(node *root){
        if(root==NULL)
            printf("\n\tEMPTY TREE!\n");
        else{
            printf("%5d",root->info);
            if(root->lptr)
                preorder(root->lptr);
            if(root->rptr)
                preorder(root->rptr);
        }
    }

    void inorder(node *root){
        if(root==NULL)
                printf("\n\tEMPTY TREE!\n");
        else{
                if(root->lptr)
                    inorder(root->lptr);
                printf("%5d",root->info);
                if(root->rptr)
                    inorder(root->rptr);
        }
    }

    void postorder(node *root){
        if(root==NULL)
            printf("\n\tEMPTY TREE!\n");
        else{
            if(root->lptr)
                    inorder(root->lptr);
            if(root->rptr)
                    inorder(root->rptr);
            printf("%5d",root->info);
        }
    }
```

Comment: GDB is your friend go ask him http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a substitute for basic debugging skills. We're not going to do all the work for you. Please try to at least reduce your code to the simplest for that reproduces the problem; in doing so you'll likely discovered the bug yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is on these lines about 10 lines into your insert function:

```
if(root=NULL)
    root=p;
```

You are assigning root to NULL instead of comparing it to NULL. Then, since NULL evaluates to false, root does not get assigned p. In fact those two lines **guarantee** that root *is* NULL after they execute. You just need to add an `=` to make it a comparison like:

```
if(root == NULL)
    root = p;
```

This is just an aside, but I recommend putting spaces around your comparison operators. It would make this error much more noticeable, and would make lines like: `val>parent->info` much more readable, as that line could easily be mistaken for `val->parent->info`

**Edit**

As Mark pointed out in the comment below, since `==` is commutative, but `=` isn't, you can also avoid this error by switching the order of the operands when you have a value on one side. If you put it on the left like `(0 == root)` or `(NULL == root)`. The compiler will catch the error for you if you leave an `=` out since `(0 = root)` is not syntactically correct.

Comment: thank you very much. I made this kind of mistakes a lot of times...

Comment: @joansky You're welcome, feel free to accept my answer if it helped you :) There's a checkbox under the vote count to do that.

Comment: @joansky - If you make this kind of error a lot, you can use a trick many use where you put the value on the left side of the comparison (e.g. `if ( NULL == root )`) .  This way, if you write `if (NULL=root)` by mistake, the compiler will catch it for you as you can't change the value of a constant.  It makes no sense, and the compiler agrees, to say `let 0 = root`.

Comment: @Mark +1 That's a very useful trick if you make that mistake often. It's a good practice to get into when you're just starting out too

Comment: Paul and Mark, thanks a lot for the advice. I will do that in the future.